# I am trying to center this select dropdown, how can I do it?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

As you can see below the select dropdown is not centred and is slightly positioned to the right and showing the select arrows. how can I make this drop down centered as to hide the arrows ..[image: select dropdown options]

```css
.select-input {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.input-label {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.select-input-text {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(33, 36, 37);
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 1.36;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(228, 231, 234);
    border-image: initial;
    outline: none;

}
```

```html
<div class="select-input">
 <label for="company" class="input-label">company</label>
 <select class="select-input-text" style="width: 300px;">
 <option disabled="disabled" value="">select a category</option>
    <option value="">manufacturer</option>
    <option value="">retailer</option>
     <option value="">distributor</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @AlonEitan my mistake thought the visual would be enough . let me add the code

Comment: No problem. Once you added the code i'll be happy to upvote and will definitely retract my close vote

Comment: @AlonEitan check it out and feedback will be greatly appreciated  ....